# Does WSO2 EMM (MDM) support OMA DM and/or TR-069 client participation?

Tags: mdm, oma

WSO2 EMM looks like a very interesting effort.  I am looking for OMA-DM and optionally TR-069 client support as well.  In other words, the ability of a device with an OMA-DM client to enroll and be managed by WSO2 EMM.    One might say that what want is an OMA-DM server, but in fact, I am looking for a server that can address both mobile device (smartphone/tablet) as well as "other" device management options.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 EMM](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/) doesn't support OMA-DM or TR-069 client support (yet). As a core developer involved in the project I would certainly raise these protocols as important features to address in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

From WSO2 EMM right now what we have tried (please note that I am a core team member) to address is the management of mobile platforms which are popular these days. For this we have dealt with the MDM APIs provided by the platforms. For this its not necessary to dig into the implementation details of MDM protocol under each platform since its upto the MDM vendor to provide and implement it.

Note: As far as I know Windows supports OMA-DM. Anyway in a future release there will be Windows phone support.

To add additionally to your point, if you think it from a different angel its also possible to integrate OMA-DM clients. For this the implementation of the EMM needs to be done adhering to the server aspect of the protocol. Yes this is perfectly possible and if there are real use cases or need we might go for it.